# Get the clicked table row element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I know this already asked here. I referred this [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315600/jquery-getting-the-text-value-of-a-table-cell-in-the-same-row-as-a-clicked-ele) , [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987000/jquery-on-click-table-row-find-value-of-contained-input-text) but working the same in jquery mobile not able to get the value. I want to get column A value how to get this one.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by0nsp0p/15/) what i tried

Code is like:

```
onclick="deleteRow(this)"

function deleteRow(r) {
$(r).parent().parent().hide();

var Something = $(r).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
alert(Something);
// this one gave the input element as child 
alert($(r).parent().parent().children().children().html);
alert($(r).parent().parent().children().children().text());
```

}

check this also [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/520/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text you're looking for is actually the value of the `input` within the first `td`, so you need to get the `val()` of that element, not the `text()` of the `td`. Also note that `eq()` takes the index which is zero-based, so you need to use `0` to get the first `td` of the row. Try this:

```
function deleteRow(r) {
    var $row = $(r).closest('tr').hide();
    var Something = $row.find('td:eq(0) input').val();
    alert(Something);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/by0nsp0p/16/)